# How can you summarize growth in the "production" rate per person?

Tags: excel, descriptive-statistics, business-intelligence, pivot-table

I have been reading the book, *Good to Great* by Jim Collins.  It says that you should focus on information that "cannot be ignored," and that you should focus on the right "denominator."

I thought it would be good to measure "Average Growth Rate per Producing Entity." If we are providing value and support, we would expect to be helping them "produce more."

I have production data in an excel spreadsheet that I can summarize.

I primarily use "pivot tables" for my data analysis.  I know that you can do "percentage change over previous time period" but I end up with distortions for the first year, when people don't have a full period to produce.  I also am not sure how to summarize it.

Is there a better program that I should use for this? Is there a good way to do this in excel?

I was thinking you could take the geometric mean (what growth rate would you need on the initial production number in order to end up with the final number -- or so I believe it is explained) and besides that I'm not sure where to start.  I would love to use pivot tables or something similar where I can just hit refresh and get the updated version of the numbers.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 2):

I think the standard thing to use is the [annualized rate](http://glossary.reuters.com/index.php/Annualized_Rate).  If you have less than one year, you simply multiply the current observed value by the reciprocal of the proportion of a year that it represents.  For example, if you have one month (1/12th of a year), you multiply by 12, for one quarter, you multiply by 4, with just 16 days, you multiply by 365/16, etc.  With observations over a shorter time period, you will have more measurement error in your estimate, as you suspect.  Unfortunately, this is unavoidable.  As for better software, I would argue that a programming language (such as `R`) may offer advantages in the long run, but require a lot of effort to learn up front.  For a project such as this, it may not be worth it.

Comment: Yeah. Annualization would work but it would have to be done manually. :(

Comment: If you have a column in which the proportion of the year covered by each datum is noted, you should be able to pretty easily code up a new column w/ a function that will compute the appropriate multiplicative factor & then drag or copy-&-paste that function across the needed range of cells. That shouldn't take too long. As I note above, learning a programming language that will allow you to do this with a few lines of reusable code will pay off in the long run, but will require an investment of time up front.

Comment: I am comfortable with PHP for programming and I have been able to make some visual basic work within excel...

Comment: I don't know PHP, nor do I really know visual basic, but you should be able to make the latter work to calculate the multiplicative factors for you in excel.